# Using NSCoding appropriately in a grandparent-parent-child data model relationships

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

I have a grandparent, parent and child model relationship (the `Orchestra` class model object, which contains many `Section`s, and each contains many `Player`s). In other words, the `Orchestra` object has property called `var allSections: [Section]`, and the `Section` object has a property called `var allPlayers: [Player]`

My goal is to persist the data for all three models using `NSCoding`. **I am confused about whether I should conform to `NSCoding` for** (A) all 3 classes, (B) only the child class, or (C) all the classes besides the child class? One source of my confusion is the fact that [`NSCoding` is recrusive][1].

So far, I have implemented the standard `NSCoding` protocol methods for `Player`:

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "playerName")
        aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "playerId")
        aCoder.encode(playerStatus, forKey: "playerStatus")
        aCoder.encode(playerPosition, forKey: "playerPosition")

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "playerName") as! String
        id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "playerId") as! String
        playerStatus = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "playerStatus") as! PlayerStatus
        playerPosition = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "playerPosition") as! PlayerPosition

        super.init()

    }
```

And in the `init` method for `Section` I will call:

```
if let archivedItems = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: itemArchivalURL.path) as? [Item] {
            allPlayers = archivedItems
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 must conform to `NSCoding` if you wish to archive an instance of an `Orchestra`.

If you only want to archive a `Section` instance that only `Section` and `Player` must conform to `NSCoding`.

Think of it this way. Whatever object you wish to archive must itself conform to `NSCoding`. And anything you need to encode/decode in that class must also conform to `NSCoding`. And that needs to hold true all the way for all classes that will ultimately need to be encoded/decoded.

Comment: This for the helpful explanation. I ran into an issue where, while `allSections` do populate, the property `allPlayers` (which belongs to `Section`) does not get populated despite saving. I added more to the question body with code to explain the issue.

Comment: Your original question was answered. I suggest you close out this original question and you post a new question with your new issue. Include all relevant code and clearly explain the issue you are having with the encoding/decoding.

Comment: Got it. Will unbundle per your suggestion.